# Need WebCalendar like Functionality with Rails or Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I need an end-to-end Calendar, Schedule Management Solution that integrates with my Rails Application.

I need it to be able to handle events, meetings, reminders, exports and imports etc.

Something Like WebCalendar is for Php.

I know there is a Google Calendar API available for Ruby but I am not sure if that's suitable for internal use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is a development framework. It's by no means a system (some call it CMS) that you can plug modules in that offer end-to-end functionality.

There are some good plugins and gems around, but none will truely offer you an out-of-the-box solution.

Of course, there are some gems that can help you along building a calendar app. I personally like Chronic for easy time usage. For the rest, the basic Ruby Time and DateTime classes and the extensions to it in Rails should be sufficient.

Comment: I understand that its a dev framework, by no means a CMS, there have been plugings like Railendar ( which i don't think is maintained anymore ). I know there are some good plugins like CalendarHelper and Chronic. My Idea was to find something that I can reuse instead of rolling out my own. Thanks anyway

Comment: Code re-use is great. Rails promotes it with gems and plugins, but you don't want code reuse, you want component re-use, which is something else entirely. My advice is to look into rails' engines and see how that goes for you. I'm not aware of any pre-made component you could use, nor do I thing that'd be a good idea.